Query regarding determinants - getting different results from different methods.
$
\begin{vmatrix}
(1+a) & 1 & 1    & 1 \\
1 &(1+b)& 1 &   1 \\
1 & 1  &(1+c) &   1 \\
1  &1  & 1   &(1+d) \\
\end{vmatrix}
$
This determinant is solved using two ways
Way 1 operate
$R_1 + (R_2+R_3+R_4)$
$C_2 - C_1,C_3 - C_1,C_4-C_1$
This gives
$det = abcd(1+  a^-1 +b^-1+c^-1+d^-1)$
Other way is to express det as
$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1     & 1 \\
1 &1& 1 &    1 \\
1 & 1  &1 &   1 \\
1  &1  & 1   &1 \\
\end{vmatrix}
+ 
\begin{vmatrix}
a& 0 & 0 &  0 \\0 &b&0 &    0\\
0& 0  &c &    0 \\
0  &0 & 0    &d \\
\end{vmatrix}
$
This gives det = abcd
Why results are different in the two cases

way 2 should be $\begin{vmatrix}
a& 0 & 0 &  0 \0 &b&0 &    0\
0& 0  &c &    0 \
0  &0 & 0    &d \
\end{vmatrix}$ then apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

The second computation is wrong: The determinant is not a linear functions, it is multilinear. We do not have that $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$, but we have that
$$
\det(a_1,\dots,a_i+a_i',\dots,a_n) = \det(a_1,\dots,a_i,\dots,a_n)+\det(a_1,\dots,a_i',\dots,a_n)
$$
where $a_1,\dots,a_i,a_i',\dots,a_n$ are column vectors. So in your computation you must have
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1+a & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1+b & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1+c & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1+d
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1+b & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1+c & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1+d
\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}
a & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1+b & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1+c & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1+d
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Then you can continue expanding each determinant using the same rule.
Also, you said nothing about $a,b,c,d$ being nonzero, so the answer given by the first procedure, which is the right answer provided this hypothesis, must be written as $abcd+abc+abd+acd+bcd$.
